# Rules for dash between subject and predicate when the predicate is an adjective

Tags: пунктуация, прилагательные

I'm a native Russian speaker, but I'm a little ashamed that I don't quite know the rules for when I need to use a dash.

Let's consider a very simple sentence:

**Маша (—) умная и красивая.**

Do we need a dash between Маша and умная, and why?

In general, what are the rules for dash usage when the predicate of the sentence is an adjective?

**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Сказуемое является прилагательным.**

I'd like to consult some websites — preferably reputable sources.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/правила_русской_орфографии_и_пунктуации_лопатин/тире_между_членами_предложения/#id-3Тиремеждучленамипредложения-§15

Comment: Сергей, спасибо.  Там написано, что "тире возможно при наличии однородных сказуемых". Хотелось бы понять, почему возможно, а не нужно или необходимо. А то как-то размыто выходит: хочешь — ставь, не хочешь — не ставь. Могу копать, могу не копать. Но если следовать этому принципу, то получится, что в предложении "Она была молода и умна" нужно тире, так как вообще-то здесь два однородных сказуемых, и они выражены прилагательными.

Comment: Вот практически ваш пример: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=306101

Comment: Так там сказуемое "спортсменка"... а я хочу рассмотреть пример, когда сказуемое — прилагательное, причём их несколько. Или, ещё лучше, когда одно сказуемое прилагательное, второе — причастие... Нужно ли тогда ставить тире. Или же хозяин барин: хочешь — ставь, хочешь — как хочешь... Странное будет правило, ну да ладно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Маша умная и красивая.

В данном случае тире не нужно, но при наличии «структурного параллелизма» тире ставится:

- Маша — умная и красивая. Миша — добрый и сильный.

> Тире **не** ставится:
>
> 4. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным или причастием: А твоя комната такая хорошая для ребенка (Ч.); У меня много хороших людей, почти все хорошие  (Сим.); Две раны у него были. Раны нетрудные, но человек потерял много крови (Пауст.); Сруб розовый, облупившийся, по-деревенски маленький, покрытый зеленой железной крышей  (Кав.); Суровой осени печален поздний вид (Забол.); В столовой пир горяч  и пылок  (Забол.).
>
> > Однако при сказуемом-прилагательном тире ставится при структурном параллелизме частей предложения, сопровождаемом в устной речи интонационным выделением (ударением) обоих членов предложения: Все в ее облике обращало на себя внимание: взгляд — острый, прическа — мальчишеская, одежда — современная, модная; ср. при акцентном выделении только сказуемого: Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый, лошади не везут, а виноват смотритель (П.). Тире возможно и при наличии нескольких (однородных) сказуемых: Сын у нее — желтый, длинный и в очках (М. Г.).

[https://orfogrammka.ru/правила_русской_орфографии_и_пунктуации_лопатин/тире_между_членами_предложения/#id-3Тиремеждучленамипредложения-§15](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-3%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A715)

Другие ваши примеры:

> "Она была молода и умна" нужно тире

Не нужно, т.к. есть связка "была":

> §10 Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым *на месте отсутствующей связки* ставится тире

(Курсив мой.)

> хочешь — ставь, не хочешь — не ставь

Совсем другая конструкция, тире выражает причинно-следственную связь + опять же cтруктурный параллелизм присутствует.

- Могу копать, могу не копать

Совсем другая конструкция — цепочка глаголов (модальный + инфинитив).

> Там написано, что "тире возможно при наличии однородных сказуемых". Хотелось бы понять, почему возможно, а не нужно или необходимо.

Хороший вопрос! Поделюсь своими домыслами. На мой взгляд, однородность тут неважна. Да и в примере у Лопатина определения не очень-то однородные (желтый, длинный и в очках). Важно интонационное оформление: если говорится гладко, на одном дыхании:

- Маша умная и красивая.

то тире не ставится. А если после "Маша" сделать небольшую паузу и начать ее (Машу) расхваливать:

- Маша — умная, красивая, не замужем!

то тире как раз «заполняет» эту паузу. В этом случае сказуемое — *перечисление* качеств, а не просто одно или два однородных определения.

Повторюсь, важна интонация: если после подлежащего небольшая пауза, а элементы сказуемого произносятся с интонационным контуром перечисления, то тире ставится.

Т.е. ответ на ваш вопрос «почему возможно» – потому что можно прочитать и так, и так, и соответственно написать можно с тире и без.

Answer (score 0):

Вне контекста ваш вопрос не имеет ответа. В ряде случаев тире проставляется в зависимости от содержимого предыдущего текста.

Справочники вообще не решают проблему выдуманных предложений. Пунктуация - не физика, а ситуативное решение конкретной интонационной задачи.